# Characterization of a line segment

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I want to prove that a curve $\alpha: I \to \mathbb R ^2$ parameterized by arc length is a segment of a line iff the intersection of all its tangents is not empty.

To prove the interesting direction, I formalized the hypothesis as saying that $p_0 = \alpha (s) + \lambda (s) T_\alpha(s)$ for certain $\lambda(s)$.

But then I did two apparently innocuous steps and got a nonsensical result. Namely, I multiplied by the normal vector $N(s)$. Since the normal vector its orthogonal to the tangent vector, we get $p_0 N(s) = \alpha(s) N_\alpha (s)+ \lambda (s) T_\alpha(s)N_\alpha (s) = \alpha(s) N_\alpha (s)$.

But since the normal vector is unitary, I can multiply again by it to eliminate it from the equation, which gets me $p_0 = \alpha(s)$ which is obviously wrong.

What is going on?

Comment: $p_0N(s) = \alpha(s) N(s)$ is actually an identity of scalar products, .i.e. $\langle p_0 , N(s) \rangle = \langle \alpha(s) , N(s)\rangle$. There is no way you can eliminate $N$ from that.

Comment: You really need to write *dot* or *scalar* product in your equations. You're losing track of what things mean.

Comment: Am I missing something? Do you really mean *all* tangents? For a fixed point $p$ and a fixed unit tangent $\mathbf{v}_p$ at $p$, all of the vectors $\{\epsilon\mathbf{v}_p\}_{\epsilon>0}$ are tangent at $p$, and $\bigcap\limits_{\epsilon>0}\epsilon\mathbf{v}_p$ is the single point $p$. But then the intersection of all tangents for all $p$ is empty. So do you mean tangent *lines*, rather than tangent *vectors*?

Comment: @MPW by tangent I mean the infinite line that is tangent to the curve in a given point

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: In your equation, $p_0$ is a constant vector function. So differentiate your equation and use Frenet. This is the always the standard approach in basic differential geometry!

Comment: Of course this is the standard thing to do. You must not forget however to prove that $λ(s)$ is indeed smooth.

Comment: Well, @NickA., smooth may be overkill, but, yes, we need to know $\lambda$ is a differentiable function.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that multiplication means inner product. Therefore, if you have $<p_0,N(S)>=<a(s),N_a(s)>$ you **cannot** deduce that $p_0=a(s)$. You are on the right track however.

Let me present a different approach. Using the implicit function theorem , locally you can assume your curve is a graph of some function. Therefore  Rolle's theorem stands. Therefore for any two points $p_1,p_2$ (not on a local extremum) in the region there exists a tangent parallel to the line joining these points. But this tangent intersects the tangents at $p_1,p_2$.

If all the points lie in an extremum then we have nothing to prove because locally our curves is a line and since it is smooth also globaly.